# Select random object from array and decrement value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to know how can I randomly select an object from an array and decrement the value of `valid`.

I have the following:

```
const codes = [
   {
      code: "AG1",
      valid: 20
   },
   {
      code: "AG2",
      valid: 20
   },
   {
      code: "AG3",
      valid: 20
   }
]
```

Now I select the object random like this

```
var code = codes[Math.floor(Math.random()*codes.length)];
```

After I select an object I need to decrement the object's value of valid by one

Any idea?

Comment: This question doesn't seem related to JSON at all, and so I've removed the `JSON` tag. That said, your code selects an object, of which you want to subtract `1` from its `valid` property. So, `code.valid = code.valid - 1` would do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to keep the changes on the array you can just use `codes[idx].valid--` after you got the random `index`:

```js
const codes = [
   {code: "AG1", valid: 20},
   {code: "AG2", valid: 20},
   {code: "AG3", valid: 20}
];

const decRandom = (codes) =>
{
    let idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * codes.length);

    // Decrement only if greater then zero.
    codes[idx].valid > 0 && codes[idx].valid--;
}

let iteration = 0;

setInterval(() =>
{
    decRandom(codes);
    console.log("Iteration: " + ++iteration, JSON.stringify(codes));
}, 2000);
```

Comment: And how do I stop decrementing if the value is equal with 0?

Comment: You can use a condition `codes[idx].valid > 0 && codes[idx].valid--;` I'm updating with this...

Answer (score 2):

You can use -- to decrement

```js
var codes = [{
    code: "AG1",
    valid: 20
  },
  {
    code: "AG2",
    valid: 20
  },
  {
    code: "AG3",
    valid: 20
  }
]

var rand=Math.floor(Math.random() * codes.length);
console.log(codes[rand].valid!=0?--codes[rand].valid:codes[rand].valid);
```

Comment: Since he wants to decrement `valid` *after* selecting the element, you could do post-decrement:  `var code = codes[Math.floor(Math.random()*codes.length)].valid--;`